# Can you identify this red insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Location: Lansdowne, Uttarakhand, India

Date: 27 May 2017

Time: 5.33 pm

The insect was found walking upwards on a plastic table. It was about 3-4cm long, as far as I remember; its been a long time since I encountered it.
Spotted near a small shack in the Terai forests.
[image][image]

Comment: A note as to the animal's size might help (there isn't quite enough here to get that); other than that, I'm certain it's a true bug (Order Hemiptera, Suborder Heteroptera), and believe it to be a stink bug relative (Superfamily Pentatomoidea), but not knowing the Indian fauna I can't go deeper than that.

Comment: It looks like a nymph of eusthenes femoralis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nymph of a [shield bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomoidea) in the [Tessaratomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessaratomidae) family, commonly called **tassarotimids** (or sometimes "giant shield bugs" due to typically being 1.5 - 4.5 cm long).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessaratomidae#Classification_and_distribution):

> They are mostly found in tropical Africa, Asia, and Oceania though a few species can be found in the Neotropics and Australia. There are about 240 species known

Of the subtaxa, only a few genera are even found in India: 
*Empysarus*, *Neosalica*, and numerous in the subtribe Eusthenaria (e.g., *Asiarcha*, *Aurungabada*, *Carpona*, and *Dalcantha*). A key (Leston (1955)<sup>+</sup>)to this group of insects is available for purchase or institutional subscription on [Wiley](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-3113.1955.tb01477.x)

**Specific Taxa:**

Similar to a [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/84698/can-you-identify-this-red-insect#comment150957_84698) under the OP's post suggests, [this page](https://www.pinterest.com/vicwicked/tessaratomidae/) appears to suggest that the nymph of a Eusthenarian called *Eurostus validus* (shown below) appears quite similar to the OP's specimen. However, I cannot find definitive record of *E. validus* being in India.

[image]

<sup>Source: Vic wicked on [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/vicwicked/tessaratomidae/)</sup>

the availability of useful information (keys, reputable websites, etc.) for this group of insects (especially for India and in English) are extremely limited, so I will just leave you here with the understanding that your insect is a tassarotimid nymph that is closely closely related to *Eurostus validus*, *Eusthenes femoralis* or some other member of the Eusthenaria.

---

<sup>+ Leston, D., 1955, April. A KEY TO THE GENERA OF ONCOMERINI STÅL (HETEROPTERA: PENTATOMIDAE, TESSARATOMINAE), WITH THE DESCRIPTION OF A NEW GENUS AND SPECIES FROM AUSTRALIA AND NEW SYNONYMY. *In Proceedings of the Royal Entomological Society of London. Series B, Taxonomy* (Vol. 24, No. 3‐4, pp. 62-68). Oxford, UK: Blackwell Publishing Ltd.</sup>